# pandas iterate throw rows to see if value is alpha numeric

Tags: python, string, pandas

so i have a df with a column that has various string values

```
col1

Hi
-Hi
+hi
=Hi
```

I would like to remove all of the non alpha numeric values in this column to this:

```
col1

Hi
Hi
hi
Hi
```

I know i can just do a str replace with those non alpha characters, but to future proof the script, I would like to use something like isalpha(). there might be different non alpha characters in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
df['col1'] = [''.join([i for i in x if i.isalpha()]) for x in df['col1']]

print(df)

  col1
0   Hi
1   Hi
2   hi
3   Hi
```

If you have `NaN` or `float` values, remove them *first* by converting them to empty string:

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').notnull(), 'col1'] = ''
```

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable error.

Comment: @skimchi1993, See update.

Comment: so if i have HI-Hello. it would go to Hihello and not just Hi-Hello. I want to only remove it if the first character is alpha numeric like -Hi = Hi

Comment: @skimchi1993, But that wasn't your question. Don't change your question, please. I have rolled it back. If you have a new, different question, ask it separately.

Comment: got it! thats my fault. this does work so i will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions:

```
df['col1'].str.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+').apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))
```

**Output:**

```
0  Hi
1  Hi
2  hi
3  Hi
```

Comment: this removes non alpha characters even if it not in the front. so something like Hi-hello comes Hi

Comment: @skimchi1993 you are right. Updated. Now it's ok.